# Server for SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration

What will be the best Server Configuration for SQL 2008 as on date with DB Size of 5 GB?

So far my experience with Desktops, AMD processors gives better performance than of Intel.  Is Opteron processors are better for SQL 2008 or should I stick with Intel Xeon.

Comment: "what is the best..." questions are virtually unanswerable due to the multitude of possible requirements which are frequently omitted in such questions - just as has happened in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have an extreme amount of traffic, it most likely won't make any difference if you've got modern dedicated hardware for a DB of just 5 gigabytes. With just 8GB of memory you can probably get a cache hit ratio of ~100% which will render disks less important, except for the logs.

As for CPU's I personally prefer Xeons over AMDs line of CPU's, but I have no facts to base it on besides personal experience.

Comment: 5 GB is current db size with 2 years data.  And it's growing.  No. of concurrent users are 20.  It may go up to 30 this year.  My inserts and updates are taking long time and users have to wait till screen finishes its work.

Comment: But how have you concluded that it's lack of CPU power? What profiling have you done? Before throwing hardware at it, you should be absolutely certain of where your bottleneck is, or you may just waste money. 20-30 concurrent users is not much for a 5GB database. Either those users are very heavy users or there are some more fundamental problems at hand, which should be identified first.

Comment: @Sivaa, throwing money or hardware at the problem merely hides it. Best thing to do is FIX it by performing proper analysis and redesigning and/or recoding as necessary.